# GenericRepository pattern Update method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am trying to use unitofwork and repository pattern and I have the following "update" method which works fine if I am replacing all the elements in a table row (id, color, year).

```
public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
{
    dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
    (entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

But I want to update just the specific columns that I am passing (id & color). it will overwrite the other elements (year).

So for example, I have a database record in my Cars table:

```
Id = 1,
color = "red"
year = 2010
```

if I update it like so...

```
var location = new Car
{
    Id = 1,
    color = "blue"
};


unitOfWork.CarRepository.Update(car);
```

the record is now:

```
Id = 1,
color = "blue"
year = null
```

How can I rewrite my generic repository method to just change what I feed it? (ie keep the year value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will not be able to do so reasonably with the generic repository pattern. You really have no need to use this pattern. EntityFramework is already a generic repository why would you need to wrap it in another generic repository? This type of abstraction adds negative value.

You do want to encapsulate your database usage from your controller (there shouldn't ever be a DbContext in a MVC controller) you however don't need any special patterns to do so. Just inject the DbContext into a class that does work.

Also the unit of work pattern for the most part is an anti-pattern if you pass the UOW around. This creates some really insane coupling issues in your application that wholly unrelated code is able to impact vastly different segment of code.

Dropping the generic repository and using EF directly inside your service/DAL/resource class (whatever you want to call it) will allow you the full functionality of EF. This will allow doing partial updates very trivially.

To do partial updates with a generic repository you will need some heavy duty dynamic code for dealing with mapping. Honestly I could theoretically write this, but I know enough to know **not to write this**. The more and more abstract you make mapping the more brittle it becomes, it is next to impossible to predict the future for how to deal with mapping. This is why there are entire libraries like AutoMapper for dealing with the infinite numbers of combinations of how mapping can be done. AutoMapper is also somewhat if a misnomer too, while it can do basic automapping for the most part the use case of AutoMapper is still all **static mapping** not dynamic mapping. You would need to create dynamic mapping aka crystal ball mapping.

Comment: How would you test your service/DAL/resource when using entity directly? Wouldn't you have to mock every entity method used in the service/DAL/resource method(s) you need to test to be able to do that?

Comment: @afarazit i never mock a database, that's pointless. I mock the abstraction, the 'DAL'. Sometimes that might mean my mocked DAL uses dictionaries to simulate persistence for [fast] integration tests.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic - Can you point to some article which describes the implementation of mocking DAL instead of databases. Because I too have been mocking db to test my services.

Comment: @Nanu i don't. It's pointless to mock a database, you're testing nothing at that point. you have no idea that your code could work, it doesn't matter if it worked against a mocked database. you just wasted tons of effort.

Answer (score 0):

The update method you've written assumes you have started with an existing entity object with properties set. The repository assumes that your business logic works like this:

```
var car = repo.GetCar(id);

car.prop1 = "new value";
car.prop2 = "another new value";

repo.update(car);
```

This will keep any previous values you had set.